# how do I access a character from 2-D char string

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, printf, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 50
#define len 30
char text[max][len];
void main(){
    register int i;
    printf("Enter an empty line to quit\n");
    for(i =0 ;i<max;i++){
        gets(text[i]);
        if(!*text[i]){break;}
    }
puts(text[1][0]);/*I want to display first character of second string but it doesn't print anything. Why??*/
}
```

how do i access character or part of string from array of string

Comment: Never use `gets`. It was removed from the language in C11 because it's unsafe. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Change `puts()` to `putchar()` to print one character..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use standard C function `fgets`.

The function `puts` expects an argument of the pointer type `char *` that points to a string. However you are passing an object of the type `char`

```
puts(text[1][0]);
```

that invokes undefined behavior.

Also declare variables in minimum scope where they are used. There is no great sense to declare the array `text` in the file scope.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 50
#define LEN 30

int main( void )
{
    char text[MAX][LEN] = { 0 };

    puts( "Enter an empty line to quit" );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < MAX && fgets( text[i], LEN, stdin ) != NULL && text[i][0] != '\n' ) 
    {
        ++i;
    }

    if ( !( i < 2 ) ) printf( "%c\n", text[1][0] );
}
```

Pay attention to that the function `fgets` can store the new line character `'\n'` in the suppled array.

If you want to remove it then you can write for example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

text[i][ strcspn( text[i], "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `puts(text[1][0])` is trying to print a `text[1][0]` which is a `char`, and `puts` only accepts an `char*`, leading to a segmentation fault on my computer.

But, `printf` allows you to print an `char`.

Fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 50
#define len 30
char text[max][len];
void main(){
    register int i;
    printf("Enter an empty line to quit\n");
    for(i =0 ;i<max;i++){
        gets(text[i]);
        if(!*text[i]){break;}
    }
printf("%c\n", text[1][0]); /* printf allows you to print char */
}
```

Note: as said in the comments of the question, you can also use `putchar()` to print one character.

Input:

```
s
s
```

Output:

```
s
```